# WordPress wp_query + filter result (no custom filed) + next_post_link()

Tags: wordpress

I did an extensive search but could not find the answer (perhaps I'm not using the right search terms?).

Anyway, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm using wp_query to return user submitted posts that have been published. I am showing one post at a time and using next_posts_link() to let the user to advance to the next post. This is all working fine. I'm also using the [wp-postratings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/) plugin to the user to rate these user submissions. I only want to show posts that the user has not already rated. For that, I'm using:

```
check_rated_username($post->ID)
```

This part is actually also working. So far my code looks like this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
));
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    $rated = check_rated_username($post->ID);
        if (!$rated) : ?>
            <?php //the_title() etc. Show post details (it's long so I'm not going to post the whole thing, but the post details are showing up fine) ?>
            <?php next_posts_link('Next &rarr;', 10); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

**The problem** next_posts_link() retrieves posts that meet the parameters set in the wp_query (and therefore are not part of the "if (!rated)" statement.  There are instances when I click on "Next", and it shows a blank page--a post that this particular user has already rated.

How can I set it up so that I'm showing one post that the user has not rated on each page AND allow the user to navigate to the next unrated post by clicking on a NEXT button? I'm not married to the approach I have come up with. I just need to achieve this end result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first to fetch all posts id:s that a user has rate, then you can add an `post__not_in` in your query. It can look something like this:

```php
<?php 
/* Get all posts id:s that current user has rated */
$user_ratings = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT rating_postid FROM {$wpdb->ratings} WHERE rating_userid = %d", get_current_user_id() ) ); ?>

<?php
/*Set up an empty array for save id:s in */
$post_not_in = array();

/* Check if $userRating has any values, if so loop thru and put the id into the array */
if($user_ratings){
  foreach($user_ratings as $user_rating){
    $post_not_in[] = $user_rating->rating_postid;
  }
}
?>
<?php
/* The loop */
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post__not_in' => $post_not_in
);
$my_query =  new WP_Query($args);?>

The rest of your code
```

This way the loop only have posts that the current user haven't rated yet.

Comment: Thank you! This worked beautifully. I was banging my head against the wall because I never considered using post__not_in. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad i could help you out :)